# Generic form of solutions to a first order PDE.

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

I am looking for vector field solutions to
$$\partial_a (u_b u_c) = \partial_b (u_au_c)$$
Primarily in 2D, but a generalization would also be nice to have.

Notation: $u_a$ is the $a$th component of the vector (truly: one form) $u$. There are $n$ components and $n$ dimensions. The partial derivative $\partial_a$ is the differentiation with respect to the $a$th coordinate.

Comment: The way the question is written implies that $a, b, c$ are coordinates for a single function $u$, so I'm not sure where you expect to get a vector field from. If so, this is equivalent to $$u_{ab} u_{c} + u_{b} u_{ac} = u_{ab} u_{c} + u_{a} u_{bc} \implies u_{b} u_{ac} = u_{a} u_{bc}$$ and separating implies $u_{c} = u$ i.e $u = e^{c} f(a, b)$

Comment: @MatthewCassell My bad; I should have made the notation clearer!